# Web Audio API getByteTimeDomainData not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I am trying to visualize audio with the Audio Web API, it is working in Chrome and Firefox but not in Safari (desktop mac).

This is a minimal example that is logging the frequencyData in Chrome, but in Safari it is always an array of a lot of 128 values, even when the music is playing.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <audio id="audio" crossOrigin="anonymous" src="https://...." controls />
  <script>
    const element = document.getElementById('audio');

    const context = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
    const analyser = context.createAnalyser();

    const source = context.createMediaElementSource(element);
    source.connect(analyser);

    analyser.connect(context.destination);
    analyser.fftSize = 2048;

    const frequencyData = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);

    setInterval(() => {
      analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(frequencyData);

      console.log(frequencyData);
    }, 1000);

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The source is an mp3 stream coming from an Icecast2 server. I have not found any information about specific issues for Safari about this... Is there something specific that is not supported in Safari?

Comment: Han I was right actually, made a typo while double checking... So your problem is that you are not initializing this context in an user-gesture. You can refer to [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52583704/audio-plays-in-chrome-but-not-safari/52583913#52583913)  to find a way to do it long before you need the context, e.g from a splash-screen. But if you can simply initialize everything in a click event, you'd be good: http://jsfiddle.net/6y0dp9e2/

Comment: I thought that did only apply to mobile safari, it is weird that there is no hint about this in the browser. But in my example the audio is not autoplaying, is the play button in the audio controls not enough as a user gesture?

Comment: no, because you started the audio context before. It doesn't matter that the mediaElementSource doesn't output sound at this time, you connected to destination, they mute everything. And since the click event should not be catchable on the mediaelement UI, you can't really use thos event (better do the inverse as in my fiddle).

Comment: Awesome, that seems to work! I accept your comments as answer if you add them as one.

Comment: Ok, so I actually got your example to work (I am using this inside an React application and it did work there also) but, I am using audio streams, not and audio file, and that still does not work. Is there a limitation about this in Safari?